# Ad Videos Won't Play

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, bugs, ads

on my device, ad videos just won't play. In some games you need to watch ads in order to get in game currency, which is not possible for me. When I click on "Watch Ad", a black frame pops up and immediately closes itself. 
To my knowledge, I do not have any ad blockers installed. If you need any logs or whatever just tell me and I will put them up.

Edit:

- OnePlus One A0001
- Android 5.1.1
- Paranoid Version 5.1 (20150822)
- Apps I'm talking about:
  AdVenture Capitalist (double payouts)
  Lords & Knights (Gold videos)

Comment: Can you link the source from where you downloaded your PA build? The official website is not giving any result for bacon?